# get the value out of a textbox php and match with database

Tags: php, database, match, assign

i wan to create a form and match the values of the form to the database. i have tried but i fail and have a werid error.  CSRF state token does not match one provided. i am new and need some help

```
   <?php
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
include_once "fbmain.php";
include_once "mysqli.connect.php";
mysql_connect(".....") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("jetstardatabase") or die(mysql_error()) ;

?>    
<html>
    <link type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="starpickStyle.css">

    <head>
        <title>StarPick</title>

    </head>
    <body>
<?php
if (!isset($_POST["code"]))
{
?>

<form action="" method="post">

 <strong>Code: *</strong> <input type="text"  name = "code" >
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
}else
{
$code = $_POST["code"]; }
$sql = "SELECT bookingref FROM starpick WHERE obsolete = 0";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{           
    if($row->bookingref == $code)
    {
        echo 'Found';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Try Again';
    }
}
?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching it wrong, you need to let the database do the matching, not get all rows and do the matching in php.

Something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT bookingref FROM starpick WHERE obsolete = 0 AND bookingref='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["code"]) . "'";    // better use a prepared statement by the way but you'll have to check the manual for mysqli
```

and then just check if a row if found.

I'm using PDO myself, but here is [manual on prepared statements for mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: @Nicholas Lim You need to add some error handling to your mysqli calls, starting with the first one where you connect with the database. Can you post the complete code (without username / password)?